# Confidence level for clusters

Tags: clustering

I have a sample, set of outcomes of some random variable. I divide it into "clusters", using some determinate approach. One of the clusters considered to be "correct", usually it is the one that has the most number of outcomes in it, but not always. I want to mark each cluster with some "confidence level", based on the number of outcomes it has. The formulae should depend on the number of outcomes in each cluster totally, and in the current one.

Say, if the outcome numbers, for each cluster sequentially, are: `220, 31, 28, 21`, then the first cluster should have very high confidence level, something close to 100%, but not exactly 100%. But if the distribution is `113, 110, 106, 103`, then all the confidences should be almost equal - and *not* even close to 100% - since there are several similar clusters, we cannot mark each of them as "probably correct".

I cannot use just relative proportion to the maximum, because it will cause highest cluster to have always exactly 100% confidence level, and it shouldn't be.

Is there some approach, or formulae, that gives such estimations? Thank you.

Comment: The most direct measure would be the proportion of outcomes in that cluster, not relative to the maximum but to the sum, so in your examples it would be `0.733, 0.103, 0.093, 0.070` and `0.262, 0.255, 0.245, 0.238`, respectively. If that doesn't suit your purposes, you should say in what way you want it to differ from that. Would you want the cluster with `220` to have a higher confidence level than 73%?

Comment: @joriki This approach is sensitive to the sum, not to the actual numbers and their differences. Firstly, for first example 73% is too low, it should be more than 90%. But this sentence is not so mathematically strict. Secondly, what's more important, if there's one cluster with `100` outcomes, and ten with `10` outcomes each, then first will be measured as 50% confidence, when in reality in such situation first cluster is almost always correct. So, more "noise" - more confidence that not-noisy cluster is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the conditional probabilities for the outcomes to be the correct outcomes under a prior assumption that the correct outcome occurs with some probability $p$ and all incorrect outcomes occur with probability $q=(1-p)/(n-1)$, where $n$ is the number of different outcomes. Then the probability for outcomes $a_i$ with sum $\sum_ia_i=S$ if answer $k$ is correct is proportional to $p^{a_k}q^{S-a_k}$, so you could assign confidence levels

$$c_k=\frac{p^{a_k}q^{S-a_k}}{\sum_i p^{a_i}q^{S-a_i}}=\frac{p^{a_k}q^{-a_k}}{\sum_i p^{a_i}q^{-a_i}}\;.$$

You can choose the parameter $p$ according to your needs. For $p=q=1/n$, you'll get $c_k=1/n$ (which makes sense, since if you assume that people are just guessing, no amount of clustering will raise your confidence in one of the outcomes). For $p$ near $1$, you'll get sharply peaked confidence levels even for moderate differences in the outcome counts. In the limit $p\to1$, $q\to0$ the confidence level for the outcome with the highest count will go to $1$ and the others will go to $0$, since you can multiply through by the lowest number of factors of $q$ and the other terms in the sum go to zero.

If you want the confidence level in your first example to be noticeably different from $100\%$, you'd have to choose $p$ quite close to $1/n=25\%$. Here are some values for your examples:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
p&q&220&31&28&21\\
\hline
0.253&0.249&
0.879&0.043&0.041&0.037\\
\hline
0.256&0.248&0.994&0.002&0.002&0.002\\
\hline
0.259&0.247&1.000&0.000&0.000&0.000
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
p&q&113&110&106&103\\
\hline
0.253&0.249&
0.270&0.258&0.242&0.230\\
\hline
0.256&0.248&0.291&0.264&0.233&0.212\\
\hline
0.259&0.247&0.312&0.270&0.224&0.194\\
\hline
0.265&0.245&
0.354&0.280&0.204&0.162\\
\hline
0.280&0.240&0.458&0.288&0.156&0.098\\
\hline
0.310&0.230&0.632&0.258&0.078&0.032
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Why do you have the same photo as a [different user](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/6622/joriki) on math.SE?

Comment: My question is: why do I have a different name here? :-) I'm the same person, but here my real name is being displayed and on math.SE my screen name is displayed -- I have no idea why this happened; if you know how I can change it I'd appreciate it :-)

Comment: Interesting -- the screen name was set to my real name. That shouldn't happen.

Comment: Well, that's a good alternate question! No, I don't know the answer. But, perhaps the moderators do. It's probably some account merging issue. I'll flag them and maybe they can help.

Comment: Yes, I agree. That should not happen. May be good to alert meta.SO.

Comment: I've flagged this post to get the duplicate accounts figured out. It appears to me @joriki has made a seperate account for the German language site, and that was the one that was associated when answering this question. I assume you would want all the accounts merged?

Comment: OK, thanks! I will use p = (max a_k / Sum a_k) + 2-3%, it works fine.

Comment: @joriki You just don't have those accounts associated; this probably mean you used different OpenID here and different on Maths and SO. One way of solving this would be to go to your [profile on Maths](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/6622/joriki), clicking "add openid" and then choosing "log in with StackExchange" and log in using your web.de email (this is the OpenID you use here, I can't see that used on Maths and SO). This should trigger automatic association procedure; you would get a +100 reputation bonus here and be able to log in with either of openids.

Comment: @joriki, accounts issue aside, welcome to stats.SE!